# Native C++ Code in Android Studio with a Static Library

Tags: c++, android-studio, gradle, cmake, static-libraries

I am trying to make a native C++ code in Android Studio and with CMake. My C++ code uses precompiled static library (.a file). 
I included its header .h in my C++ code. I also linked the location of the .h and the .a files in my CMakeList.txt as below:

```
include_directories(".h file location")
```

Then:

```
add_library(lib_fastcv STATIC IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(lib_fastcv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ".a file location")
```

And at the end:

```
target_link_libraries (...lib_fastcv....)
```

However, as soon as I use any function from the .a static library it complains that it cannot recognize the function which means the static library is not linked correctly to my C++ code.

Does anyone know what else I need to do?
Should I also edit my build.gradle to include information about the library file?

Comment: Are you sure the .a file contains code appropriate for the architecture you're compiling for? Also, CMake `target_link_libraries` does not take commas between arguments.

Comment: I am not sure about that. I have 32 bit anf 64 bit version of the .a file. I tried both and did not work.
I will try to specify in build.gradle a specific build and see if it works.

For 
target_link_libraries
, You are right I just mentioned it this way in my post and already edited it.

Comment: I configure build.gradle to make for a specific ABI and still no luck.... I suspect it might be related to CMake version is not compatible with the .a prebuilt file. Otherwise I have no clue why it is not able to use the .a file provided to it!

Comment: The cmake version has nothing to do with this. What architecture are you compiling for, what architectures are your .a files and does `nm` prove that the missing symbols are in there?

Comment: I got it working. It was related to how CMake should be directed to existing code .a file as well as how build.gradle should be told to build for specific abi format. To me it seems it's still unnecessary complicated!!  I will post the part of my code related to this problem later.  Thanks for your initial response it helped me to look for the problem in the right place.

Comment: Good that you got it working. It's pretty simple actually: the build system will invoke CMake for every ABI in turn, with [ANDROID_ABI](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake#android_abi) set to the target ABI. It is up to you to ensure that the imported library points to the correct .a file.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution:
So, first of all, CMake can be weird to use at the beginning.

1- native-lib1 is the output product of CMake. Later java will only see .so of this

```
add_library( # This is out .so product (libnative-lib1.so)
    native-lib1

    # Sets the library as a shared library.
    SHARED

    # These are the input .cpp source files
    native-lib.cpp
    SRC2.cpp
    Any other cpp/c source file you want to compile
    )
```

2- Any library that you included in your souse file, its .h needs to be addressed here:

```
 target_include_directories(# This is out .so product (libnative-lib1.so)
    native-lib1 PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

3- Any actual library you used, its atual .a or .cpp should be addrressed to CMake this way:

```
target_link_libraries(
    # This is out .so product (libnative-lib1.so)
    native-lib1

    #These are any extra library files that I need for building my source .cpp files to final .so product
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libfastcv.a
    # Links the target library to the log library
    # included in the NDK.
    ${log-lib})
```

Then build.gradle it should be mentioned what abi formats we want it to make to make sure you pre built .a files are compatible.

```
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
    create("arm7") {
        ndk.abiFilters("armeabi-v7a")
    }
```

Finally, as a note, the below command did not work to filter abis and above command work, even though they look similar in logic and form to me:

```
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-std=c++11"
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }
    ndk {
        // Specifies the ABI configurations of your native
        // libraries Gradle should build and package with your APK.
        // This is not working to eliminate
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
    }
}
```